# CUDA out of memory. Although there is 23GBs free

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

trying to train BERT on a local GPU, RTX 6000 with 24GB of memory. I am able to manage the memory usage of the models on my other project. However, when trying to train this model it throws an error instantly. I cannot even see it trying to fill up the GPU. I tried changing the batch size but I do not think that is the issue.

> OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 90.00 MiB (GPU
> 2; 22.17 GiB total capacity; 29.00 KiB already allocated; 3.81 MiB
> free; 2.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >>
> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.
> See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Trying to implement this: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/multiple_choice

Changes to the code:

```
torch.ones((1, 1)).to("cuda")
model = AutoModelForMultipleChoice.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased").to("cuda")
```

Do I have to add any changes to the trainer?

Comment: when exactly does it fail? just when moving the mode to gpu? The one line you've pasted only takes 1.3G for me. During training? first batch or? do you have multiple GPUs locally (I see "GPU 2" in your output). If `GPU 2` why 'cuda' not 'cuda:1'?... more info in general would help.

Comment: @nairbv it fails when I run trainer.train(). Moving mode to gpu executes fine. I can see the increase in memory usage at that point. When trying to train it fails straight away, saying the error above. I do not see it processing any batches at all, so I would assume on the first one.

Comment: The GPU is a cluster of 4, having cuda takes the 0th ID, which is empty, as well as the first one. So it doesn't really matter which one I use, as long as I annotated all the GPUs the same; 'cuda' or 'cuda:1'